# How can I set up gVim as my editor on Git for Windows?

Tags: windows, git, vim

I'd like to use gVim as my editor for Git commit messages. I realize Git has its own version of vim, but it's not quite the same as gVim (along with my _vimrc settings) which I use all day anyhow.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use gVim with Git by configuring your `core.editor` to contain the path where you have gVim installed. You'll also want to run it in the foreground and not load your _viminfo file, which would position your cursor in the place where you finished your previous commit message.

Taking note of the single and double quotes, you might do something like this:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe' -f -i NONE"
```

Comment: If you installed vim with the "create batch files" option, you can also do: `git config --global core.editor "'C:\Windows\gvim.bat' -f -i NONE"`.  This way you'll survive a vim update and things will still work.

Comment: I can confirm `gvim.bat` works on Windows 10 under Git for Windows (MinGW).  I like this solution because there's no need to reconfigure Git when you upgrade Vim; it should just continue to work because the batch files are not version-specific.