# gvim 8.2 doesn't redraw the screen when editing a git commit message in windows 10 powershell

Tags: powershell, vim, windows-10

I installed `vim` on windows 10 using [`chocolatey`](https://chocolatey.org/). When I edit a file in powershell, everything works great! [I even got copy and paste to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62619756/9636). However, when I edit a git commit message, `vim` doesn't redraw my screen properly. If I [force a screen redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1117731/9636), I can see my updated text properly, but that is super annoying.

I configured `git` to use `vim` with:

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

How can I make `vim` behave properly?

Comment: Moved to superuser: https://superuser.com/q/1564620/42083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

Giving git the direct fully-qualified path to my vim executable fixed things, and I don't know why:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\tools\vim\vim82\vim.exe' -f -i NONE"
```

Single quotes around the path are important because `git` doesn't know how to handle paths with backslashes.
Double quotes around the whole configuration are important so that git doesn't apply `-f -f NONE` to the `git config` command.
I found `-f -i NONE` on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28952307/9636), and I don't know what it does, but `git commit` didn't work without it.

**How I found the full path**

`vim` adds a `c:\windows\vim.bat` file, which is what `powershell` uses to launch `vim` when you type `vim`:

```
PS C:\Users\heath> Get-Command vim

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     vim.bat                                            0.0.0.0    C:\windows\vim.bat
```

`vim.bat` is pretty simple:

```
@echo off
rem -- Run Vim --
rem # uninstall key: vim82 #

setlocal
set VIM_EXE_DIR=C:\tools\vim\vim82
if exist "%VIM%\vim82\vim.exe" set VIM_EXE_DIR=%VIM%\vim82
if exist "%VIMRUNTIME%\vim.exe" set VIM_EXE_DIR=%VIMRUNTIME%

if not exist "%VIM_EXE_DIR%\vim.exe" (
    echo "%VIM_EXE_DIR%\vim.exe" not found
    goto :eof
)

"%VIM_EXE_DIR%\vim.exe"  %*
```

Thus, my full `vim` path is `C:\tools\vim\vim82\vim.exe`

Comment: Moved to superuser: https://superuser.com/a/1564621/42083